# ngix many redirect to https version

Tags: docker, nginx

I want to create autoredirect from http to https version of my site. This is my nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  server_tokens off;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/certbot;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend:4200;
#     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
    rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
  }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://example.com;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

If uncomment this string: `#     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;` i see to many redirect and my site isn't work. How to right configure nging for this case.

Comment: Your server listening on 443 is forwarding the request back to 80 using `proxy_pass`, you are therefore creating an infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comment `szt` you are right.

This is my new config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  server_tokens off;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/certbot;
  }

  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend:4200;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
    rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1 break;
  }
}
```